# Python algorithm to get all 3x3 grids in a 9x9 grid

Tags: python, algorithm

I have this python function to find all the elements in the 3x3 grids from a 9x9 grid (think sudoku):

```
def get_grids(grid):
    out = []
    for i in [0, 3, 6]:
        for j in [0, 3, 6]:
            g = ""
            for m in range(i, i + 3):
                for n in range(j, j + 3):
                    g += str(grid[m][n])
            out.append([int(g_) for g_ in g])
    return out
```

If I set `g = 0` then `g += grid[m][n]` it will just add the numbers, i.e. not what I want. But it seems the wrong approach.

I think there would be a better way to approach this and optimise it but I'm unsure, what this would be.

```
assert get_grids(
    [
        [1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 6, 9, 8, 7],
        [4, 6, 5, 8, 7, 9, 3, 2, 1],
        [7, 9, 8, 2, 1, 3, 6, 5, 4],
        [9, 2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 8, 7, 6],
        [3, 5, 4, 7, 6, 8, 2, 1, 9],
        [6, 8, 7, 1, 9, 2, 5, 4, 3],
        [5, 7, 6, 9, 8, 1, 4, 3, 2],
        [2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 7, 1, 9, 8],
        [8, 1, 9, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 5],
    ]
) in [
    [
        [1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 8],
        [5, 4, 6, 8, 7, 9, 2, 1, 3],
        [9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4],
        [9, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7],
        [4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 1, 9, 2],
        [8, 7, 6, 2, 1, 9, 5, 4, 3],
        [5, 7, 6, 2, 4, 3, 8, 1, 9],
        [9, 8, 1, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4],
        [4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5],
    ],
    [
        [1, 4, 7, 3, 6, 9, 2, 5, 8],
        [5, 8, 2, 4, 7, 1, 6, 9, 3],
        [9, 3, 6, 8, 2, 5, 7, 1, 4],
        [9, 3, 6, 2, 5, 8, 1, 4, 7],
        [4, 7, 1, 3, 6, 9, 5, 8, 2],
        [8, 2, 5, 7, 1, 4, 6, 9, 3],
        [5, 2, 8, 7, 4, 1, 6, 3, 9],
        [9, 6, 3, 8, 5, 2, 1, 7, 4],
        [4, 1, 7, 3, 9, 6, 2, 8, 5],
    ],
]
```

Here is a quick code to check the function works correctly, so you don't need to write your own ones!

Comment: Don't work with strings, but with lists: `g = []`, then `g += [grid[m][n]]`. If your submatrices are row-wise, you can save one loop and use the slice syntax `[:]`.

Comment: your `out` target dimension is 9x3x3 .. or 9x9 ? (your code look like 9x9...not sure which target dimension fits your need  )

Comment: @p._phidot_ yeah, it's 9x9 sorry should have made that clear, I just want one list containing all the elements in the 3x3 grids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_grids(grid):
    yield from (
        (grid[m][n] for n in range(j, j + 3) for m in range(i, i + 3))
        for j in [0, 3, 6]
        for i in [0, 3, 6]
    )
```

Using a generator means it is more memory efficient.

Comment: Generators are not faster, they are slower. But they use less memory.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```py
from itertools import chain

def get_grids(grid):
    x, y = len(grid), len(grid[0])
    assert (x, y) == (9, 9)
    
    size = 3    
    out = []

    for i in range(0, x, size):
        rows = [*zip(*grid[i: i + size])]
        for j in range(0, y, size):
            out.append([*chain(*zip(*rows[j: j + size]))])
    return out
```

It uses [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to get three rows at the same time then use another zip that will take now from each row vertical slice (aka 3 columns)

[chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) is used to flatten zip's tuples to one flat list

The final result looks like:

```py
[[1, 3, 2, 4, 6, 5, 7, 9, 8],
 [5, 4, 6, 8, 7, 9, 2, 1, 3],
 [9, 8, 7, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4],
 [9, 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 8, 7],
 [4, 3, 5, 7, 6, 8, 1, 9, 2],
 [8, 7, 6, 2, 1, 9, 5, 4, 3],
 [5, 7, 6, 2, 4, 3, 8, 1, 9],
 [9, 8, 1, 6, 5, 7, 3, 2, 4],
 [4, 3, 2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5]]
```

Another option would be create matrix[9][9] and load values to it:

```
def get_grids(grid):
    l = len(grid)
    s = 3
    out = [[None]*l for _ in range(l)]
    for n in range(l):
        for m in range(l):
            k = (n // s) * s + m // s
            j = (n % s) * s + m % s
            out[k][j] = grid[n][m]
    return out
```

Or you can use traditional list comprehension

```
def get_grids(grid):
    l = len(grid)
    s = 3
    return [
        [grid[(j // s) * s + i // s][(j % s) * s + i % s] for i in range(l)] 
        for j in range(l)
    ]
```

Comment: I know this is an old answer but can you expand on the equation you are using to get the 3x3 square? I can't seem to wrap my head around this `(j // s) * s + i // s` and `(j % s) * s + i % s`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using numpy you can use reshape and swap axes to transform a 9x9 into a 3x3 matrix containing 3x3 sub-matricies.

```
A = np.array([
                   [0,0,0,3,0,1,6,0,2],
                   [0,2,0,0,0,0,7,1,0],
                   [0,0,8,0,7,0,0,0,0],
                   [2,4,0,5,3,8,1,9,0],
                   [9,8,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
                   [7,5,0,1,2,0,4,6,8],
                   [0,0,2,8,0,7,0,4,0],
                   [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,6],
                   [0,3,4,9,1,0,0,0,0]
])

B = A.reshape(3,3,3,3).swapaxes(1,2)
```

Or if you want a 1D array containing all nine  3x3 boxes:

```
B = A.reshape(3,3,3,3).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(9,3,3)
```

Or you could reshape it to a 9x9 containing the elements of each box on a row:

```
B = A.reshape(3,3,3,3).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(9,9)
```